# Could not cast value of type 'Swift._EmptyArrayStorage' to 'NSMutableArray' in iOS 11, Xcode 9

Tags: ios, swift, nsmutablearray

It looks like we can not convert an empty `var` array in Swift into `NSMutableArray` in Objective-C.

```
var adultTravelerModels: [TravelerDataModel] = []
BookDataManger.sharedInstance().arraySelectedAdultPassenager = adultTravelerModels as! NSMutableArray
/* (lldb) po adultTravelerModels
0 elements */
```

The system version is iOS 11.0, Xcode 9.0.

How can we solve this?

Comment: Why are you trying to use `NSMutableArray` in Swift? Use a Swift array.

Comment: Because I want to pass it to a NSMutableArray property in Objc.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do like this:

```
BookDataManger.sharedInstance().arraySelectedAdultPassenager = NSMutableArray(array: adultTravelerModels)
```

Answer (score 3):

In Swift 4, you can not assign swift empty array to `NSMutableArray`.
But you can construct new `NSMutableArray` and assign to where required.
Like below:

```
BookDataManger.sharedInstance().arraySelectedAdultPassenager = NSMutableArray(array: adultTravelerModels)
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to construct a new instance of `NSMutableArray`.

Comment: Sorry I choosed Andre's answer as the correct answer, to let new people have more chance :)